# How to use a list to iteratively add qlabels with delete buttons that can remove them

Tags: python, list, pyqt5, qlabel, qpushbutton

There are a lot of questions on here about creating QLabels with a QButton to delete them. However, there aren't any on how to use a list of strings to iteratively create these labels and attach the delete buttons to them.

I have tried this using the code below. It generates a lineEdit which you can drop multiple files into and it will generate a list of those files which it will iteratively turn into labels and corresponding delete buttons. It works, sort of, however, when I press the delete button on each label I get the 'RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLabel has been deleted'. I suppose that's because I've managed to create the list of labels but the delete button is only attached to one of the labels.

See my code below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QLabel, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout


global search_list
search_list = []

class LocationDrag(QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QLineEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    
    
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print(event)
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
                
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            
            dragged_files = event.mimeData().urls()
            dragged_files_paths = [url.toLocalFile() for url in event.mimeData().urls()]
            
            global search_list
            search_list.extend(dragged_files_paths)
            for item in search_list:
                name = QtWidgets.QLabel(item)
                name.setStyleSheet('QLabel{ width:90; height:30; background-color: rgb(27, 29, 35); border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid rgb(27, 29, 35); padding: 5px;}')

                deletebutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("x")
                deletebutton.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {color: red; font-weight:bold; padding:5px}')

                deletebutton.clicked.connect(lambda:delete_location(self, (name, deletebutton), item))

                demo.mainLayout.addWidget(name, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
                demo.mainLayout.addWidget(deletebutton)
                    
        

def delete_location(self, widgets, search_item):
    if search_list:
        name, deletebutton = widgets
        name.deleteLater()
        deletebutton.deleteLater()
        search_list.remove(search_item)
        

class AppDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
 
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.lineEdit_2 = LocationDrag()
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(10,35,350,30)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {\n"
        "    background-color: rgb(27, 29, 35);\n"
        "    border-radius: 5px;\n"
        "    border: 2px solid rgb(27, 29, 35);\n"
        "    padding-left: 10px;\n"
        "}\n"
        "QLineEdit:hover {\n"
        "    border: 2px solid rgb(64, 71, 88);\n"
        "}\n"
        "QLineEdit:focus {\n"
        "    border: 2px solid rgb(91, 101, 124);\n"
        "}")

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = AppDemo()
demo.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I've updated the question. Hopefully it's clearer now. If you need me to do anything else, please say.

Comment: @goodaytar yes, we need you to provide an **actual** minimal *and* reproducible example. We must be able to copy, paste and run your code. Please, carefully read and follow the suggestions in the link shared by eyllanesc.

Comment: @goodaytar That piece of code is not an MRE because if I copy and paste it I will not be able to launch the application and consequently I will not be able to analyze where the error is

Comment: Thank you both. @eyllanesc . Still getting the hang of all of this. I've updated my code now. If you run it and drag files into the QlineEdit. They generate fine but the issue occurs when you click on the 'x' to try and delete them.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting too complicated since you are leaving many tasks to a few classes, for example the LocationDrag should only obtain the routes, it should not add it to the window. On the other hand, it is better to create a widget that represents the QLabel + QPushButton row, and then each time the button is pressed the row widget is eliminated, and this elimination implies that it will be removed from the layout.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QLineEdit,
    QLabel,
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QPushButton,
    QMainWindow,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QVBoxLayout,
)


class LocationDrag(QLineEdit):
    filesChanged = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QLineEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            files = []
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                if url.isLocalFile():
                    files.append(url.toLocalFile())
            if files:
                self.filesChanged.emit(files)


class RowWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        nameLabel = QLabel(name)
        nameLabel.setStyleSheet(
            "QLabel{background-color: rgb(27, 29, 35); border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid rgb(27, 29, 35); padding: 5px;}"
        )
        deletebutton = QPushButton("x")
        deletebutton.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton {color: red; font-weight:bold; padding:5px}"
        )

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(nameLabel, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        lay.addWidget(deletebutton)
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        deletebutton.clicked.connect(self.deleteLater)


class AppDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.lineEdit = LocationDrag()
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(
            "QLineEdit {"
            "    background-color: rgb(27, 29, 35);"
            "    border-radius: 5px;"
            "    border: 2px solid rgb(27, 29, 35);"
            "    padding-left: 10px;"
            "}"
            "QLineEdit:hover {"
            "    border: 2px solid rgb(64, 71, 88);"
            "}"
            "QLineEdit:focus {"
            "    border: 2px solid rgb(91, 101, 124);"
            "}"
        )

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        self.lineEdit.filesChanged.connect(self.handle_files_changed)

    def handle_files_changed(self, files):
        for file in files:
            rowWidget = RowWidget(file)
            self.mainLayout.addWidget(rowWidget, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = AppDemo()
demo.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```